# I want to retrieve random POI near my current location using nominatim

Tags: javascript, jquery, orm, nominatim

I've been searching for a while now and all I can find is getting specific POI (point of interest) near my location, what I want is to retrieve nearby places regardless of POI type.

below is what I have so far in getting nearby places although the code only retrieved nearby cafe.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
       url : "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=cafe+near+%5B14.1832558%2C121.26603150000001%5D&format=json",
       method : "get"
   }).done(function(response){
       console.log(response);
   });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If by POI you mean more then just cafes, you'll need to specify the right `special phrase` according to the Nominatim list: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Special_Phrases. Unfortunately, I can't see anything to specify 'All'. This does support operators though, so you could render better results by using multiple special phrases.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Dandy,

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help, I'm not too familiar with openstreetmap and its functions, will update again if I find anything more concrete for you. Best of luck.

Comment: your query sound like your searching for "cafe near ...", like its name of cafe